# Error in Chrome and Safari Password Input on a Mac

Tags: html, forms, macos, google-chrome, safari

I have an application with a simple login form with two inputs: `login` and `password`.

When I write a password that contains characters with accent marks like `ô` or `á` (by typing `Option-i + o` and `Option-e + a` respectively), the browser ignores the accent mark and post the fields with regular non-accented `o` and `a`.

When I inspect the element, change the attribute `type` from `password` to `text`, the problem does not happen.

When I cut and paste an accented password, the problem does not happen either.

It's tested on Macs, using Chrome and Safari. This issue does not happen in Firefox.

Has anyone also have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug on Chrome for MacOS

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373082

Comment: This question is quite old and the answer too. But this bug raised to me today. If I try to type "á" in a password field, Chrome (and Safari) will change to "a".
Chrome: 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit)
OSX: 10.11.3 (15D21)

Any ideas?